# SPRING-HATEOAS + RestTemplate: creating resources with linked entities?

Tags: spring-hateoas

How to create resources with one-to-one relationships to existing entities? Take the simple case of a forum user. We have two top-level resources that can exist independently from each other: User & Question. If you were to post your JSON literally, you would send something like:

```
POST /api/users
{name: "John Doe", "email": "jdoe@example.com"}
```

and get back location header: http://example.com/api/users/1

Then

```
POST /api/questions
{"author": "http://example.com/api/users/1", "title": "How to do this?", "text": "I don't know how to do this..."}
```

With RestTemplate I'd be tempted to do:

```
Question q = new Question();
q.author = somePreviouslyCreatedUSerReference;
q...

template.getForLocation("/api/questions", q);
```

But what you get is the following error since the de-serializer is expecting a reference. There is a lot of documentation for consuming trivial REST endpoints but very sparse one when it comes to actually creating real world resources.

---

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.example.model.Question["author"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:197)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1420)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:118)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2993)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2158)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3023)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$UriStringDeserializer.deserialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:359)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:525)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:106)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:242)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I can consume a resource collection just fine, but I'm having issues consuming single resources. It's a pain. Been on it for over a week.